# How to properly call laravel's middleware closure in phpunit?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, laravel-middleware

How to properly call this middleware closure function in `phpunit` test so that `$user` will be set?

Auth::user is mocked and will receive the proper user object, but the function is not called when creating the controller instance.

Here is my code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CustomController extends Controller
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Phpunit:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Controllers\CustomController;

class CustomControllerTest extends TestCase
{
   use CreatesApplication;

   private $customController;

   public function setUp()
   {
      Auth::shouldReceive('user')->andReturn(new User());
      $this->customController = $this->app->make(CustomController::class);
   }
}
```

Comment: show the code of "creating the controller instance"

Comment: It's bad practice to be returning in `__construct()`

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving the controller out of the container, but then you aren't passing it any requests to handle. Your middleware code will only be executed when the controller is given something to handle.

As such, `$this->middleware(...)` simply says "execute this middleware when a request is sent through the pipeline".

Simply test a standard request hitting your endpoint, and then assert what you need to assert.

```
$this->get('your_endpoint');
```